# Extract URL minus path in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Unlike some other questions, which want to turn URLs into root domains (eg `https://www.example.com/foo` to `example.com`)...

I would like to retain the protocol and subdomain (everything leading up to the single slash following the TLD, should there be one).

Eg. `https://www.example.com/foo` to `https://www.example.com`

I tried this but got a really weird result (haha)!

`=REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"(https?:\/\/(www.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/")`

It works, sort of, but **look what happens!!** It inserts data in the next column (huh??). What's crazier, when I delete the data it breaks the formula! I have done something very wrong.

[image]

Here is my sheet for testing: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1axNd6WZJnGIC8Ydyir58twrIhRhb-p1npNeg3SHfDBg/edit#gid=0

Comment: Perhaps try a non capturing group for `www.` like `https?:\/\/(?:www.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/`

Comment: One column value for each capturing group, it is expected. You may just use `=REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"https?://[^/]*")`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Could you explain how this part of the regex works? `[^/]*` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "https?://[^/]*")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks @player0. Could you explain your formula for us? That would be great.

Comment: sure, this arrayformula extracts from A column the following pattern: string starting with `http` with or without **s** `s?` followed by `://` and get everything `*` before the first occurrence of **/** that's the: `[^/]`. if such a pattern is not found in column A `IFNA` will nullify the errors